# Why is next not gensymed?

Tags: clojure, macros, hygiene, gensym

Here `x` is gensymned because some expression passed to `and` can have `x` in it and to avoid that conflict. Then why is `next` not gensymed? Couldn't `next` lead to variable capture?

```
(defmacro and 
  ([] true)
  ([x] x)
  ([x & next]
    `(let [and# ~x]
      (if and# (and ~@next) and#))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x` is not gensymmed, and shouldn't be. The gensymmed thing here is `and#`, which is gensymmed for the usual reason: it is a synthetic binding introduced into the caller's scope for the macro's internal-only usage. `x` and `next` are none of these things:  they are not introduced as bindings, nor are they for the macro's internal-only usage. They are code snippets (a form and a seq of forms) supplied by the caller, intended to be present in the expanded body for the caller's purposes.